# How SoapFormatter and FileStream work together/

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

**FileStream** only writes **raw** bytes. When I serialize using **SoapFormatter** if I open the file I can see that there XML like text. I thought you had to encode every character to before passing it to **FileStream** and that data written to a FileStream was not passed as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I can explain it or not. But let me try.

A class, taking a Filestream  and outputting text file, can implement in various ways...

for example;

```
public class SomeClass
{
    FileStream _file = null;

    public SomeClass(FileStream f)
    {
        _file = f;
    }

    void WriteString(string s)
    {
        byte[] buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
        _file.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
    }
}
```

or

```
public class SomeClass
{
    TextWriter _Writer = null;
    public SomeClass(FileStream f) : this(new StreamWriter(f,Encoding.UTF8))
    {
    }

    public SomeClass(TextWriter tw)
    {
        _Writer = tw;
    }

    void WriteString(string s)
    {
        _Writer.Write(s);
    }
}
```